# AWS Classic load balancer HTTP listener issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

What could be the possible issues with the following
I have a classic load balancer in AWS and have two listeners

```
HTTP 80 -> HTTP 5050
HTTPS 443 -> HTTP 5050
```

In route53 I have a DNS entry `<dns.entry>`
Now comes the weird part

From cURL

`https://<dns.entry>:443` works but,
`http://<dns.entry>:80` doesn't (failed to connect)

What could be going on?

Comment: Is your load balancer accepting traffic from port 80?

Comment: isn't this rule enough `HTTP 80 -> HTTP 5050`? wdym by accepting traffic? are you talking about inbound rules/security groups? @OguzhanAygun

Comment: Yes, I meant inbound rules/security groups.

Comment: @OguzhanAygun I see three inbound rules. HTTPS 443, Custom TCP 80, HTTP 80

Comment: What are the full SGs rules?